# how access the dll in sub directory of bin . .net?

Tags: .net, dll, using

i am adding a new folder to bin in solution explorer in vs 2010 and in that folder i am having one dll file and i want to access that dll file in the  program in c#.net?
 i used using in code but i did not get the intelligence  of that dll . please help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding it as a reference.

In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.

In the Add Reference dialog box, browse to it.

[How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: See what 0xA3 said. You don't have to copy the dll to the bin folder. Using the steps above will automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add files to the target bin folder of your solution as this folder is controlled by Visual Studio.

If the library is a .NET or COM library add it as a reference.

If the libary is a native dll do the following:

1. Add the file to your project
2. Set the *Build Action* property to *Content*
3. Set the *Copy to Output Directory* property to *Copy always*

Then Visual Studio will make sure that the library gets copied to the target folder automatically where you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you asking about web solutions.
In web solutions bins doesn't have any sub folder. All the dlls reside just in the bin itself.

So drop the dll directly in bin...rebuild the full solution and you will get what you want.

Thanks